# Read json with ntlm security and PHP

Tags: php, json, ntlm

```
<?php

$json_string = file_get_contents("https://user:password@domain.com");

if (empty($json_string))
{
    echo "failed to get API";
}
else
{
    echo "success";
}
?>
```

This worked before, but ntlm has been added since and it no longer can hit that json.

Any idea what needs to be done to get it working with ntlm?
Thanks

Comment: Hava a look at this blog post http://blog.mayflower.de/125-Accessing-NTLM-secured-resources-with-PHP.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the following PHP functions "file_get_contents", "simplexml_load_file", "DOMDocument" loaded in php.ini file. Instead of "file_get_contents" you can also use "CURL".